# Count the number of specific weekdays between two dates

Tags: c#, algorithm

I would like to count number of weekdays between two dates

For example:

From :1/1/2015
To: 10/1/2015

The number of Mondays = 1

Comment: i dont need difference between 2 dates

Comment: See my updated comment

Comment: i need count of specific day between 2 dates

Comment: Do see my updated link

Answer (score 1):

Check this out
http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1421-excel-count-mondays-sundays-between-two-dates.html

the formula is included in the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You can find the first monday after (or on) the start date and the last monday before (or on) the end date, then divide the difference in days by 7. Example:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2015, 1, 10);

while (start.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday) start = start.AddDays(1);
while (end.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday) end = end.AddDays(-1);

int mondays = start > end ? 0 : (int)((end - start).TotalDays) / 7 + 1;
```